# About Jmeter Content Type -issue

Tags: jmeter

While sending a https request in Jmeter prior already i have set Content-Type as "application/json" and but output still displayed as Content-Type: text/html in response header

code
HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 02 Mar 2022 05:45:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 176
Connection: keep-alive

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse [request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header) headers and [response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header) headers, they don't have to be the same.

Response status 504 means [Gateway Timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504)

> server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not get a response in time from the upstream server that it needed in order to complete the request.

So most probably it indicates that your server is overloaded and cannot provide the response within the acceptable timeframe. You can already report it as the [botteneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)

If you want to investigate further you could:

1. Check your server logs
2. Check your server configuration it might not be [suitable for high loads](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/5-ways-to-improve-your-production-web-application-server-setup)
3. Check your server resources availability in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. It might be the case you have an [APM solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) in place, if not you can go for [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
4. Re-run your test with [profiler tool telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) enabled, this way you will get more insights